# How to display ObserveableCollection<T> in ListBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I can't bind to my `ObservableCollection<T>` within my ListBox.

I am using MVVM, WPF.

The binding for the page works. My understanding is, the Grid (not shown in code) is bound to my `DataContext`, which is my ViewModel. Therefore, my `ListBox` can bind to my object called Folders via the `Itemssource`. My Folders object is very simple, it is literally

```
private ObservableCollection<Folders> _folders;
public ObservableCollection<Folders> Folders 
{
get { return _folders; }
set
  {
      if (value == _folders)
      return;

      _folders = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Folders");
   }
}
```

and my Folders model is

```
public class Folders
{
    public string SourceFolder { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFolder { get; set; }
}
```

and lastly, my XAML

```
    <ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolderItem}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceFolder}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DestinationFolder}" />
                        <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedListItem}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The button binds/executes, but the 2 textblocks do not. I have also tried

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Folders.SourceFolder}" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Folders.DestinationFolder}" />
```

but it is the same issue. The content is not displayed  (not binding) because if I add a watch on my ViewModel, I can see the values are as they should be.

If it helps, if I update my code to

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedFolderItem.SourceFolder}" />
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedFolderItem.DestinationFolder}" />
```

then it works although this is not desired (it just loops the correct number of times but only for the 1 item!).

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why have you changed their data context?

Comment: Without the different datacontext, the button does not execute.

Comment: You only change the RelativeSource of the bindings which need it as @dowhilefor has pointed out. As a good rule of thumb, if you play with `DataContext` you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: @user7116, Thank you, I've just realised this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting a different DataContext. You don't need that, otherwise you destroy the purpose of the item template.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceFolder}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DestinationFolder}" />
        <Button Content="Edit"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.EditCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

of course if you want the buttons to work aswell, you just move the relative source you currently have to the binding of the button.

Comment: Thank you, but, if I remove the 'second' datacontext, then my Button does not bind/execute. This does resolve my issue, but creates this new one!

Comment: I updated my answer. Remember that the DataContext is inherited as long as you don't overwrite it, which you did in your original post. But for your command to work, you need that. So you just pass a different Source for the binding, which then ignores the current DataContext.

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't actually understand what the binding was doing... This is like a thousand pennies dropping at once. Beer on me for this, thank you

Comment: Check my code :) Usually Binding works by using the current DataContext, but you can easily change that with ElementName, Source or RelativeSource. In this case we just use RelativeSource to find the ListBox, take the DataContext and bind to its EditCommand property.

Comment: My command parameter would have to do the same. In this case, would I be better off not doing the binding as you have in the Command, but add it's own DataContext just for the Button?

Comment: Why bind to the selected item for the edit button? If you intend for it to edit the *current item*, just use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` which is a shortcut for the current item being templated (*-ish*).

Comment: i agree, i just copied the code. In fact, i also would consider it the better approach. Because in some special situations, especially considering focus in wpf, you might click on the button of an element, but start to edit the currently selected one, which might not be the same.

Comment: @user7116 and dowhilefor, thank you both. This has helped so much, I can't tell you how grateful I am to you both.